# How would you setup example.com with one PHP framework, example.com/support with another PHP framework?

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

Hope someone can help me and not sure if this should be here or ServerOverflow.

How would you go about setting up this while using mod_rewrite in Apache 2:

http://example.com -> regular PHP

http://example.com/members -> say CodeIgniter, etc.

http://example.com/support -> some other PHP framework

If someone can point me to an article or give me an idea, I'd be most appreciative.

(*I'm thinking maybe having them on sub-domains is best vs. folders or not a problem with folders?)

Comment: Just create two subdirectories and install the respective framework(s) in them? There might not even be any need for any .htaccess rules

Comment: **`ServerOverflow`**? Never heard of such a website. Did you mean http://serverfault.com ?

Comment: Reply-to Olivier Pons: Uhh...yes, LOL! Show's how much of the server I'm used to managing! LOL!

Comment: Pekka:

Thanks for the reply but if I'm running something for URL rewriting on http://example.com, what then happens when I want another framework/app on http://example.com/members

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security considerations make use of a proxy (mod_proxy) that maps URLs for each application to a dedicated (virtual) host / server environment.

All applications can then run more isolated to each other and if anyone of those would be exploitable, the impact would be lower.

Comment: I'll have to investigate that, haven't setup anything like that, thanks for the tip/heads-up.